# ElasticSearch view types in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How do I view the name of all types in an index?
Is there a cURL request for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all the types and its mappings

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/_mapping?pretty=true`